# Rails 3.2.7: Validate model does not exceed quantity limit (on create only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this example, I'd like to limit the number of `Things` a `Person` can have to 5:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things

  def things_limit_reached?
    self.things.count >= 5
  end
end
```

and add an error to a new `Thing` when `person.things_limit_reached?` returns true:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  validate :limit_check, :on => :create

  def limit_check
    errors.add :base, 'Things limit reached.' if person.things_limit_reached?
  end
end
```

Sadly, the above code throws the following exception whenever I try to save an existing `Thing`, even if the limit is NOT yet reached:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (3.2.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work like this (untested):

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base    
    belongs_to :person
    before_create :limit_check

    def limit_check         
      if person.things_limit_reached?
        errors.add :base, 'Things limit reached.'           
        return false
      end       
      return true
    end 
end
```

Comment: Damn, still complains about the stack level too deep.